# How to fix the error "upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: overflow" in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The code is:

```
def request():
    proxy_ip_port = '129.41.171.244:8000'

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={self.proxy_ip_port}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=PATH,
        options=options
    )

    driver.get('http://icanhazip.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

It should load the page via proxy server but every time I launch the script I see the message "upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: overflow" instead of a page. My OS is Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The problem was in overloaded proxy

Comment: Please, edit your main question saying you've solved it, or give a more detailed answer